# Check out specific Azure Repository which receives latest commit along with Self-repo checkout

Tags: azure-devops

In below code , I am able to integrate continuous integration for both repo's **(NCP001) & (NCP002)** but i want to checkout only specific repository which has received latest committed changes along with self repository in **$(Build.SourcesDirectory)** of Azure .

below yaml file has been placed in separate repository (i.e. my build application repo)

Yaml File :

```
trigger:
- main
- feature

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: NCP001_CVS1
    type: git
    name: SOA_TEST/NCP001_CVS1
    ref: main
    trigger:
    - main

  - repository: NCP002_CVS2
    type: git
    name: SOA_TEST/NCP002_CVS2
    ref: main
    trigger:
    - main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:


- checkout: self
- checkout: ??


- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```

Please suggest how can i achieve this solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we push the submission in Repo NCP001, it will trigger the build pipeline, and now you just  want  to checkout NCP001 and self repo, do not checkout NCP002, right?

We could do this via REST API and [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

There is a field `BUILD_SOURCEVERSION`, check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services)

`Build.SourceVersion`: The latest version control change of the triggering repo that is included in this build. in the Git, it is the commit ID.

We could add power shell task and call the REST API to [list commit IDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), compare the latest commit ID with the variable `Build.SourceVersion`, according to the result add new variable, then use condition in the `checkout` step.

For example:

My repo are `12`, `test` and self repo is `test repo`

YAML:

```
trigger:
 - master
 
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: 12
    type: git
    name: 12
    trigger:
      - master

  - repository: test
    type: git
    name: test
    trigger:
      - master
steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Pass Variable'
    name: PassVariable
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        $PAT="{pat token}"
        $base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PAT)"))
                  
        #Get repo latest commit ID
        $ListCommitURL = "https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{Project name}/_apis/git/repositories/{repo name, eg.test}/commits?api-version=6.0"
        $ListCommit = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ListCommitURL -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo} -Method get             
        Write-Host $ListCommit.value.commitId[0]

        $CommitURL = "https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{project name}/_apis/git/repositories/{repo name, eg.12}/commits?api-version=6.0"
        $Commit = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $CommitURL -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo} -Method get             
        Write-Host $Commit.value.commitId[0]

        #Get repo latest commit ID with variable Build.SourceVersion
        if($ListCommit.value.commitId[0] -eq '$(Build.SourceVersion)'){
           Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=RepoName;isOutput=true]test"
        }
        if($Commit.value.commitId[0] -eq '$(Build.SourceVersion)'){
           Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=RepoName;isOutput=true]12"
        }

        
  - checkout: self
  - checkout: test
    condition: eq(variables['PassVariable.RepoName'], 'test')
  - checkout: 12
    condition: eq(variables['PassVariable.RepoName'], '12')
```

Result:

push commit in `self` repo

[image]

push commit in `test` repo

[image]

push commit in `12` repo

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a ton Vito. You saved me a big deal :)

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFZsO.png`Triggered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFZsO.png%60Triggered) my result pipeline carrying committed changes`[Screenshot][1]